# Jquery Slider for profile template

Tags: loop, jquery, templates, ajax

I want to show the posts under a category in my page.The first 5 posts should be shown when the page loads and When the user clicks the next button/link next 5 posts should be shown. Currently I show all posts under the category.The following is the template I use to show all the posts under that category.I know I need to change the code.But I don't know how to change. Please Help.

```
  <div id="bloggers">
<?php $bloggers = new wp_Query("category_name=bloggers-blog&order=ASC&orderby=ID");?>
<?php 
    while ($bloggers->have_posts() ) :$bloggers->the_post(); 
    $blogger_name = get_post_custom_values("blogger_name");
    $blogger_desig = get_post_custom_values("blogger_desig");
    $blogger_profile = get_post_custom_values("blogger_profile");
?>
<div id="blogger_contents">
    <h1 style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;margin-top:10px;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <div id="blogger_image">
        <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  { 
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="blogger_name">
        <?php 
            if( is_array( $blogger_name ) )
            {
                foreach($blogger_name as $key => $value );
                echo "$value</n>"; 
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="blogger_desig">
        <?php 
            if( is_array( $blogger_desig ) )
            {
                foreach($blogger_desig as $key => $value );
                echo "$value</n></n>"; 
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="blogger_profile">
        <?php 
            if( is_array( $blogger_profile ) )
            {
                foreach($blogger_profile as $key => $value );
                echo "$value</n>"; 
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="options_to_connect" class="<?php the_ID();?>">
        <a class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement " href="#">Options To Connect</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

I need to show only 5 posts and when clicking on next I need to show the next 5( Currently There is only one)
Any suggestions for this? Hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: `...when the viewer slides to the see`? - this not clear at all, same for the link.

Comment: You see the profiles with some images of some people in that  page...On the right upper side u can see two buttons which when clicked shows the rest of the profile..

Comment: You want to build this with or without AJAX?

Comment: Both are OK for me

Comment: I'm considering adding a _close vote_ for this question. This question **is not clear**, doesn't show any research effort and asks for a "do this job for me" answer. Please define your question better, show us what you've already tried, etc. **Plus:** This question as well asks the community to do the research for a slider, etc. for you.

Comment: The Question is pretty much simple. I want to show the first 5 post in a category on page load and when clicking on next button I want to show the rest. Hope now you are clear

Comment: It is simple to you, but your attempt to communicate it is far from simple. From what i gather your question is "How do I make a carousel", to which the answer is: "Ask somewhere else". This is a JS question not a WordPress question. You already know how to output all the posts, you just don't know how to put them in a carousel. That you have done no prior research, and that you basically asked us to do your work for you is offensive and does you no favours ( wether you intended this offence is irrelevant, it happened, deal with it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use carousel javascript to get the desired output. There are various carousel available, you can use some thing like [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel).

Download the js and css from the [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel) website and en-queue it in your theme to use it. 
Note : You will have to manage the dependencies of it with jQuery.

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the query to 5 posts add the parameter `posts_per_page=5` to the WP_Query class, that way you will get 5 posts per page, and you can format them the way you want, using CSS.

```
<?php $bloggers = new WP_Query("category_name=bloggers-blog&order=ASC&orderby=ID&posts_per_page=5");?>
```

[Codex > WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is always there to help, see Pagination Parameters section.

Comment: Please Read the Question fully..!!!!!!

Comment: @MidhuN please say what your issues with answer are instead of just implying it doesn't fit.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use css and jquery to create the slider effect you want to. I don't think you need ajax, since the page would load all posts and with the display property you would hide some.

Comment: Can you give me of an example for doing it?

Comment: Can you explain using code? @togh_j